# Bayesian and frequentist connections regarding the central limit theorem

Tags: bayesian, central-limit-theorem, frequentist

I have been wondering how the central limit theorem may be useful in Bayesian statistics with potentially misspecified model distribution. Suppose $x$ is a random variable that follows an **unknown** (and possibly non-normal) population distribution $P_x$. $P_x$ depends on two parameters, the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We have observed i.i.d. samples $x_{1:n}=(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n)$ from $P_x$. I am interested in the unknown parameter $\mu$.

Now consider the case that $\sigma^2$ is known. (1) A common frequentists’ point estimate would be the sample mean $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. According to the central limit theorem (CLT), $\bar{x}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ as $n\to\infty$. (2) But from an objective Bayesian perspective (using a flat prior on $\mu$), how can we obtain the posterior distribution $\mu\mid(x_{1:n},\sigma^2)$ when $n\to\infty$ without making any distributional assumptions? May be applying the Bernstein-von Mises theorem?

Answer (score 3):

The [Bernstein-von Mises theorem says something about the asymptotic behavior of the posterior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/263640); it does not inform your choice of likelihood.

There are [approaches to unknown likelihoods in Bayesian statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/531425), most of which, however, are more complicate than your problem requires.

Because if all you want to model is a mean $\mu$ and a variance $\sigma^2$, you're effectively estimating a second-order approximation to a unimodal symmetric distribution about its mode. The distribution that is [its own 2nd-order approximation is the Gaussian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/500211).

Bottomline: just model $P_x$ as a Gaussian, [reminiscent of QMLE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/185154).

Comment: Thanks. One thing remains unclear for me: Will the Gaussian approximation be better when $N\to\infty$? I mean, $\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_i;\mu,\sigma^2)$ may be more accurately approximated asymptotically?

Comment: The convergence of the likelihood function is more than just a Bayesian question. You'll probably [find the answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/616332).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of @Durden. Here is my answer.

First, some relevant questions on this site: [question 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570503/how-would-a-bayesian-estimate-a-mean-from-a-large-sample) and [question 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467893/would-you-say-this-is-a-trade-off-between-frequentist-and-bayesian-stats) are very relevant. @Sextus Empiricus ’s [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/570606/396285) seems to utilize the idea of Bayesian synthetic likelihood:

> So we could use the likelihood function: $\mathcal{L}(\mu \vert \bar{X}) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2/n}} \exp \left(\frac{(\bar X - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2/n} \right)$

The summary statistic $\bar{x}$ is observed and we can reasonably assume it follows a normal distribution per CLT. Then the posterior $\mu\mid x_{1:n}$ (here $\sigma^2$ is omitted because it’s known and fixed) becomes $\mu\mid\bar{x}$. However, I have come up with a different explanation than replacing $x_{1:n}$ with $\bar{x}$.

Then, I provide an approach using Taylor expansion of log-likelihood. We konw in objective Bayes, the posterior distribution depends on the sum likelihood $p(x_{1:n}\mid\mu)$. For notation conveniency, let

$l(\mu)=\log p(x\mid\mu)$, the **population** log-likelihood.

$l_i(\mu)=\log p(x_i\mid\mu)$, the **individual** log-likelihood.

$\bar{l}(\mu)=\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_{1:n}\mid\mu)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_i(\mu)$, the **average** log-likelihood. This corresponds to our target **sum** of log-likelihood.

$E[l(\mu)]=\mathrm{plim}_{n\to\infty}\bar{l}(\mu)$, the **expected** log-likelihood. The asymptotics can be used in this way.

Following [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94259/396285), the expected log-likelihood can be expanded in the parameter space (differing from the sample space) as a second-order Taylor series:

$\bar{l}(\mu)=\bar{l}(\mu_0)+\bar{l}’(\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)+\frac{1}{2}\bar{l}’’(\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)^2+o^2.$

Let $\mu_0$ be the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) point, i.e. $E[l’(\mu_0)]=0$. Also, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94259/396285) said:

> Then one goes to show that the remainder converges uniformly in probability to zero...

So asymptotically ($n\to\infty$) we have

$E[l(\mu)]\approx E[l(\mu_0)]+\frac{1}{2}E[l’’(\mu_0)](\mu-\mu_0)^2,$

which is essentially a quadratic approximation. This shows that asymptotically, the **true** average (also the expected) log-likelihood can be quadratically approximated. How do we do this quadratic approximation? A practical way is to model the individual log-likelihood $l_i(\mu)$ as Gaussian, whose highest order of Taylor expansion is 2. Then their sum and average will be just quadratic.

So my conclusion: In a large-sample setting, the problems of modelling the unkonwn population distribution as Gaussian will be alleviated, which is a different perspective compared to frequentists’ CLT.

**However, I found that the Gaussian approximation error may not converge to zero at the second-order level even asymptotically, and the remaining error comes from the Fisher information differences of two models!** The true asymptotic posterior and the Gaussian-approximted asymptotic postetior are both normal, but with different variances depending on their respective Fisher information matrices, as the Bernstein-von Mises theorem shows. **This is a problem not specific to Bayesians. Frequentists too suffer from so, as the QMLE estimator does not reach the Cramer-Rao lower bound. So relying on asymptotic inference may be problematic!**

The case of unknown $\sigma^2$ would be a bit more tricky and I leave this unfinished.